# Is there a Javascript equivalent of Ruby's url_for method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

It would be useful to generate server-side URLs in Javascript. Is there a way to achieve the functionality of Ruby's url_for but on the client side?

Comment: Why do this? Your client side javascript has _no_ knowledge of your server side file structure.

Comment: The reason to do is so you can make AJAX calls to a specific controller and action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, there is https://github.com/railsware/js-routes available that brings Rails' routes to JS environment.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The only way would be to call some sort of web service that'd return the URLs to various resources/pages (not recommended).

Comment: What would be your alternative solution then? How should I manage different URLs needed to make AJAX calls that return JSON data?